# How do i find declared methods only, when doing a runtime assembly load?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, assemblies, load

I'm doing a runtime assembly load, but i don't know the names of any classes or methods. I wan't to list all classes in my assembly with their declared methods, not those inherited from System.Object.

This is the code:

```
string str = "";   
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\components.dll");    

foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsClass == true)
    {    
        str += type.Name + "\n";    
        MethodInfo[] methodInfo = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in methodInfo)
        {    
            str += "\t" + mi.Name + "\n";    
        }    
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(str);
```

This is the components.dll:

```
public class component01
{    
    public string myName = "component01";
    public string getMyName()
    {
        return myName;
    }
}

public class component02
{    
    public string myName = "component02";

    public string getMyName()
    {
        return myName;
    }
}
```

The result:

```
component01
component02

And if i remove the bindingflag:

component01
   getMyName
   ToString
   Equals
   GetHashcode
   GetType
component02
   getMyName
   ToString
   Equals
   GetHashcode
   GetType
```

I only want the `getMyName` method shown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for the flags:

```
BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
```

You may want to put in `BindingFlags.NonPublic` as well, depending on your requirements.

I would also point out that with deeper inheritance hierarchies, types can inherit members from base-types *other than* `System.Object`. If you want to keep those, but not the ones originally declared on `object`, you could:

1. Remove the  `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` flag for the `GetMethods` call.
2. Only include methods for which:

   ```
   methodInfo.GetBaseDefinition().DeclaringType != typeof(object)
   ```

Of course, you may need a different filter if your definition of "declared" method were more complicated.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I tried using both Public and DeclaredOnly previously, but this didn't work. How come i need to specify all three?

Comment: @Bildsoe: `System.Reflection.BindingFlags` is a flags-enum. When the `Instance` flag is not set, `GetMethods` doesn't include instance methods.

Comment: ok, thanks. I just thought that, if the method was any of the mentioned it would get included.

Comment: @Bildsoe: Yes, it is a little unintuitive isn't it - `Instance` works as an inclusive filter, but `DeclaredOnly` is exclusive.

Comment: Yes, a little. But of course when reading the documentation on MSDN, i can see that it is described here.